# AVAudioRecorder not recording output audio coming via speaker - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I'm developing a video call application. I want to record the outgoing call going through my app. I tried recording using AVAudioRecorder. But only the microphone input is being recorded. Output audio coming through speaker is not getting recorded. Any idea, why this is happening? Is it possible to record both (2 way) audio in one file.

Comment: Because that is exactly what it is supposed to do, grab the audio input.

Audio Input and Audio Output are handled separately.

You are getting the Audio Out from a data stream.  Use that as the source of that channel.

Comment: @ArturoAlvarado could u please explain

Comment: I am not particularly familiar with AVAudioRecorder, but in every audio api I've ever dealt with, Audio Input and Output are handled independently.  To begin with, Audio Input and Output can be handled by separate hardware.  I have never seen an API that supports recording the audio from audio Output.  Anyways, where is the Audio that you are playing out comming from?  Usually it comes from a stream that is in mp3 format or pcm format, etc...  Just save that stream.